# Generating ordered UUIds

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can we generate time sorted UUID in snowflake?
The function "UUID_STRING()" in snowflake helps to generate random UUIDs but if we want to generate sequential UUIDS or time sorted UUID or we call type-7 UUID, is there any quick way to do that using sql in snowflake and generate around ~100million rows using it to populate in a table?

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake does not support UUID 7. What you could do is import [UUID6](https://pypi.org/project/uuid6/) Python module and implement a [Python UDF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/python/udf-python-creating). See [Running pip Packages in Snowflake](https://medium.com/snowflake/running-pip-packages-in-snowflake-d43581a67439) for details.

Example:

1. Download uuid6 wheel from pypi.org
2. Create script wheel_loader.py (see the Medium article)
3. PUT the wheel and loader script to a Snowflake stage
4. Create the Python UDF (steps 5-7)
5. Import the wheel and script

```
imports=('@PYTHON_PACKAGES/wheel_loader.py',
         '@PYTHON_PACKAGES/uuid6-2023.5.2-py3-none-any.whl'
        )
```

6. In your handler function, run the wheel loader script `wheel_loader.load('TheWheelFileName.whl')`
7. After the wheel load, import from the wheel package from TheWheelPackage `import some_function, another_function`